# Extract a digit out after a quote in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have an output looks like this

```
[1] "0 found |2018-07-15 22:21:09 - no new item is submitted "
```

How can I extract **0** out with "grep" using regular expression in bash?

Thank you!

Comment: `awk -F '[ "]' '{print $3}'`

Comment: maybe `grep -oP '"\K\d+'`  helps

Comment: If you are really looking for the `0` at `"0...`, then a simple `-o` (only matching) `-w` (word) setup is all you need, e.g. `grep -ow 0'. Then simply echo your string (or use a *here-string*), e.g. `echo [1] "0 found |2018-07-15 22:21:09 - no new item is submitted " | grep -ow 0' which results in a lone `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If ok with `awk`. could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'match($0,/\"[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

OR

```
your_command | awk 'match($0,/\"[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `grep` option:

```
grep -Po '^([0-9]+) (?=found)'
```

### Demo

The line above uses the pattern `^([0-9]+) (?=found)`, which says to match a number at the start of the line which is immediately followed by the text `found`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one sed solution

```
$ sed 's/^.*"\(.*\) found .*/\1/' <<< '[1] "0 found |2018-07-15 22:21:09 - no new 
item is submitted "'
0
```

If perl counts, here is one more easy way

```
$ perl -ne 'print $1 if /(\d+) found/' <<< '[1] "0 found |2018-07-15 22:21:09 - no 
new item is submitted "'
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I also come up this solution:

$LOG_FILE is the file that I am going to write all my outputs

```
grep -oE '\[1\] " *[0-9]' $LOG_FILE | cut -d"\"" -f2 | head -1
```